# Aggregation binding SAPUi5 from JSON files

Tags: sapui5

I am an intern working with SAP UI5, and I am having difficulties accessing the data in my JSON file to a table
My JSON data is in the format as so (This is a snippet):

```
[   
      {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "<UNKNOWN>",
      "area": "core",
      "cmakeComponents": [
         {
            "id": "RemoteSupportDaemon",
            "name": "RemoteSupportDaemon"
         }
       ],
       ......
      },
      {
      ........
      }

]
```

I am trying to load my JSON files from the manifest.json file as so:

```
            "models": {
        "i18n": {
            "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
            "settings": {
                "bundleName": "opensap_DashAnalytics.i18n.i18n"
            }
        },
        "data": {
            "type": "sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel",
            "uri": "model/component_XXX.json"
        },
        "component": {
            "type": "sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel",
            "uri": "model/component_SSS.json"
        }
    }
```

And I am trying to use that data in my view to make a table with:

```
                    <!--sap.m.table-->
                <Table
                id="idTable"
                items= "{path:'{data>/}',
                        mode: 'sap.ui.model.BindingMode.OneWay'}"
               .....
                >
                    <headerToolbar>
                        <Toolbar>
                            <Title text="Orange"/>
                        </Toolbar>
                    </headerToolbar>
                    <columns>
                        <Column>
                            <Text text="Component" />
                        </Column>
                        <Column>
                            <Text text="Number of failed Tests" />
                        </Column>
                        <Column>
                            <Text text="Number of Bugs" />
                        </Column>
                        <Column>
                            <Text text="Total Tests" />
                        </Column>
                        <Column>
                            <Text text="Pass/Fail Ratio" />
                        </Column>
                    </columns>
                    <items>
                        <ColumnListItem         
                        press= "onItemSelected"
                        type= "Navigation">
                            <cells>
                                <ObjectListItem title="{data>name}"/>   
                            </cells>
                           .........
                           .........
                        </ColumnListItem>
                    </items>
                </Table>
```

When I run my code, my table displays NO DATA

I have an assumption that the problem has to deal with how I am writing my path variable, or something related. 
I was wondering if there were anyone who would be familiar with this problem that could help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a wrong syntax in table 'items' aggregation

```
<Table
  id="idTable"
  items= "{path:'data>/',
  mode: 'sap.ui.model.BindingMode.OneWay'}"
>
```

Furthermore, remember that the number of cells should be the same to the number of columns to work properly

```
<cells>
  <ObjectListItem title="{data>name}"/>  
  <ObjectListItem title="{data>otherProperty1}"/>  
  <ObjectListItem title="{data>otherProperty2}"/>  
  <ObjectListItem title="{data>otherProperty3}"/>  
  <ObjectListItem title="{data>otherProperty4}"/>   
</cells>
```